# How to stretch Layout to fill screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have simple layout like this: (it's for mail)

```
<ScrollView android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@color/red_start">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@color/blue_start">

            <TextView style="@style/MyTextViewLabel" android:text="From" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/shape_white_rounded">
                <TextView style="@style/MyTextViewLabel.Black" android:id="@+id/tv_sender" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView style="@style/MyTextViewLabel" android:text="Subject" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/shape_white_rounded">
                <TextView style="@style/MyTextViewLabel.Black" android:id="@+id/tv_subject" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView style="@style/MyTextViewLabel" android:text="Body" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/shape_white_rounded">
                <TextView style="@style/MyTextViewLabel.Black" android:id="@+id/tv_body" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

For some reason LinearLayout won't fill ScrollView as I expect. Basically, I want to make tv_body to fill screen and if there is more text - it should be scrollable. Right now it looks like this. I added colors to illustrate that ScrollView stretch but LinearLayout doesn't..

[image]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try to add

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

in your ScrollView.

Checkout this for more explanations : http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/

Comment: I have nested Linear layouts inside the Scroll View. It doesn't work in that case :(

Comment: The "top" one should have height="fill_parent", beside that, there is no reason it would not work... you should post your problem in another question if you still have problems

Comment: you saved me buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change `android:layout_height="0dp"` in your ScrollView to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`?